# Bug: MathJax `enclose` environment not behaving as expected even when we write `\require{enclose}`

Tags: bug, mathjax, markdown, markdown-preview

I am having difficulty using the [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/697677) plugin on the electrical engineering stack exchange. When I write `\require{enclose}`, the `enclose` library does not work as expected (or maybe it is not a "*library*", it is an "*environment*").

The fully rendered result shows a lot of red-colored text

[image: screen capture of rendered mathjax code using the enclose environment]

```
$ \require{enclose} $  

$\begin{array}{ccccccccc}   
\Large{\enclose{circle}{A}} & \xrightarrow{0.1} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{B}} & \xrightarrow{0.2} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{C}} & \xleftarrow{0.3} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{D}} & \xleftarrow{0.4} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{E}}\\\
\scriptsize{0.5}\large{\downarrow} & \scriptsize{0.6}\large{\searrow} & \scriptsize{0.7}\large{\downarrow} & \scriptsize{0.8}\large{\nearrow} & \scriptsize{0.9}\large{\downarrow} & \scriptsize{0.1}\large{\swarrow} & \scriptsize{0.2}\large{\downarrow} & \scriptsize{0.3}\large{\nwarrow} & \scriptsize{0.4}\large{\downarrow}\\\  
\Large{\enclose{circle}{F}} & \xrightarrow[0.5]{} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{G}} & \xrightarrow[0.6]{} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{H}} & \xleftarrow[0.7]{} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{I}} & \xleftarrow[0.8]{} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{J}}\\
\circlearrowright\tfrac12\\ 
\end{array} $
```

Comment: I think the EE site uses `\$` rather than `$` as the in-line delimiters. Note that your delimiters are not being removed, which indicates that MathJax isn't processing them as Math delimiters.  The array environment is processed because any `\begin{xyz} ... \end{xyz}` delimiters are treated as display math delimiters.

Answer (score 3):

Is *this* what you intended to display?

Using `\$ ... \$`:

\$\require{enclose}\begin{array}{ccccccccc}   
\Large{\enclose{circle}{A}} & \xrightarrow{0.1} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{B}} & \xrightarrow{0.2} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{C}} & \xleftarrow{0.3} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{D}} & \xleftarrow{0.4} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{E}}\\\
\scriptsize{0.5}\large{\downarrow} & \scriptsize{0.6}\large{\searrow} & \scriptsize{0.7}\large{\downarrow} & \scriptsize{0.8}\large{\nearrow} & \scriptsize{0.9}\large{\downarrow} & \scriptsize{0.1}\large{\swarrow} & \scriptsize{0.2}\large{\downarrow} & \scriptsize{0.3}\large{\nwarrow} & \scriptsize{0.4}\large{\downarrow}\\\  
\Large{\enclose{circle}{F}} & \xrightarrow[0.5]{} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{G}} & \xrightarrow[0.6]{} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{H}} & \xleftarrow[0.7]{} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{I}} & \xleftarrow[0.8]{} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{J}}\\
\circlearrowright\tfrac12\\ 
\end{array}
\$

```
\$\require{enclose}\begin{array}{ccccccccc}   
\Large{\enclose{circle}{A}} & \xrightarrow{0.1} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{B}} & \xrightarrow{0.2} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{C}} & \xleftarrow{0.3} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{D}} & \xleftarrow{0.4} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{E}}\\\
\scriptsize{0.5}\large{\downarrow} & \scriptsize{0.6}\large{\searrow} & \scriptsize{0.7}\large{\downarrow} & \scriptsize{0.8}\large{\nearrow} & \scriptsize{0.9}\large{\downarrow} & \scriptsize{0.1}\large{\swarrow} & \scriptsize{0.2}\large{\downarrow} & \scriptsize{0.3}\large{\nwarrow} & \scriptsize{0.4}\large{\downarrow}\\\  
\Large{\enclose{circle}{F}} & \xrightarrow[0.5]{} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{G}} & \xrightarrow[0.6]{} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{H}} & \xleftarrow[0.7]{} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{I}} & \xleftarrow[0.8]{} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{J}}\\
\circlearrowright\tfrac12\\ 
\end{array}\$
```

Or `$$ ... $$` for a 'block'/'region' (I don't know the correct terminology):

$$
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}   
\Large{\enclose{circle}{A}} & \xrightarrow{0.1} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{B}} & \xrightarrow{0.2} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{C}} & \xleftarrow{0.3} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{D}} & \xleftarrow{0.4} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{E}}\\\
\scriptsize{0.5}\large{\downarrow} & \scriptsize{0.6}\large{\searrow} & \scriptsize{0.7}\large{\downarrow} & \scriptsize{0.8}\large{\nearrow} & \scriptsize{0.9}\large{\downarrow} & \scriptsize{0.1}\large{\swarrow} & \scriptsize{0.2}\large{\downarrow} & \scriptsize{0.3}\large{\nwarrow} & \scriptsize{0.4}\large{\downarrow}\\\  
\Large{\enclose{circle}{F}} & \xrightarrow[0.5]{} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{G}} & \xrightarrow[0.6]{} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{H}} & \xleftarrow[0.7]{} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{I}} & \xleftarrow[0.8]{} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{J}}\\
\circlearrowright\tfrac12\\ 
\end{array}
$$

```
$$
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}   
\Large{\enclose{circle}{A}} & \xrightarrow{0.1} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{B}} & \xrightarrow{0.2} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{C}} & \xleftarrow{0.3} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{D}} & \xleftarrow{0.4} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{E}}\\\
\scriptsize{0.5}\large{\downarrow} & \scriptsize{0.6}\large{\searrow} & \scriptsize{0.7}\large{\downarrow} & \scriptsize{0.8}\large{\nearrow} & \scriptsize{0.9}\large{\downarrow} & \scriptsize{0.1}\large{\swarrow} & \scriptsize{0.2}\large{\downarrow} & \scriptsize{0.3}\large{\nwarrow} & \scriptsize{0.4}\large{\downarrow}\\\  
\Large{\enclose{circle}{F}} & \xrightarrow[0.5]{} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{G}} & \xrightarrow[0.6]{} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{H}} & \xleftarrow[0.7]{} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{I}} & \xleftarrow[0.8]{} & \Large{\enclose{circle}{J}}\\
\circlearrowright\tfrac12\\ 
\end{array}
$$
```